# What are some good resources for learning how to AppleScript with Xcode 4.3.2?

Tags: applescript, xcode, resources

I AppleScript quite a bit and I'd like to start working with Xcode 4.3.2, so that I can expand the functionality of the things I'm writing. However, I have *no* idea how to use Xcode, nor how to AppleScript within it. Where can I find some good resources for learning how to AppleScript with Xcode 4.3.2?

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X Automation has sample Xcode projects and a few videos for getting started with AppleScript in Xcode. They also have a comprehensive book, *AppleScriptObjC Explored*, which you can buy from their site. (I can't vouch for it as I haven't read it, but their free resources are excellent.)

You can start here:

http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/develop/index.html